# How to match a String in a line having immediate special character?

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

I have given one condition like below which can not able to match line like `from table1;` or `insert into table1(col1,col2 ..)`

```
if(Arrays.asList(line.split("\"")).contains("table1")) || 
        Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).contains("table1"))
    System.out.println(line);
```

Which logic i need to follow ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to get as a result.

Comment: I want to find the exact string \btable1\b and to exclude "table1id" type of strings. I also want to catches lines like those i have mentioned in description like **from table1;** or **insert into table1(col1,col2 ..)**

Comment: So you know what `\b` is, which means you should know that this can be done with a simple regular expression rather than splitting. Why don't you try matching that regex that you gave (`\btable1\b`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression and place all the special characters which you need to split inside that expression.

```
if(Arrays.asList(line.split("[\",\s\.]").contains("table1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex match as below

```
if(Arrays.asList(line.split("[\", .]").contains("table1"))
```

Note that you can put whatever characters you want to split the line against in the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(list.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]")).contains("table1")) {
        System.out.println(list);
}
```

Or as RealSkeptic suggests use regular expression matching:

```
if (list.matches(".*\\btable1\\b.*")) {
        System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{L})table1(?!\\p{L})");
    if (pat.matcher(line).find())
    {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you can achieve it without using Splits:

```
 String stringPattern = ".*table1.*";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(stringPattern);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
 if (matcher.matches())
  System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp with negative lookahed and negative lookbehind:

```
String input = "from table1;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])table1(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);

if (matcher.find()) 
    System.out.println(input);
```

This will match any `"table1"` occurences where it is not preceded or followed by any letters, numbers or _ sign.